# Comport Package Library for Embarcadero RAD Studio XE for C++ modules

Tags: delphi, c++builder, delphi-xe

I'm trying to install the [Comport package](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=76595&atid=547603) in a Embarcadero RAD Studio XE. For the Delphi forms, the pallete appears with all comport modules (and functional,i am very sure ), but when I create a C++ form, the comport pallete appears, but with no modules inside.

I also have an installed old version of comport on Borland C++ Builder 6.0 and it works pretty well, so I'd also like to use this on Embarcadero's RAD.

Does someone know how can I fix it ? I mean, how can I make the cport modules to appear in the C++ form mode?

Thank you.

**Update**

Just a comment, the how-2-path to set the "Generate all C++Builder files (including package libs)" is the following:

1. In Delphi mode, open DsgnCPortDXE.bpl
2. Set the

   *Project >> Options >> Delphi Compiler >> Output - C/C++ >> C/C++ Output file generation >> Generate all C++Builder files (including package libs)*

Comment: I removed the `borland` and `embarcadero` tags, as they're meaningless. Anyone who knows what `Delphi` or `C++Builder` are also knows who makes them, and anyone who doesn't won't know the answer to your question. Adding those tags is like adding `Microsoft` as a tag for `Visual Studio` or `SQL Server` or `Excel`. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you compile the package, make sure the Delphi Linker's "Generate all C++Builder files" option is enabled in the Project Options.

Comment: If you've previously built/installed them without having this setting correct, you may have to delete the PackageCache in the registry for the components to install correctly.  (trying to be version nonspecific here) HKCU\Software\[Borland|CodeGear]\x.0\PackageCache

Comment: @DavidDean, setting the Project Options correctly worked as well, but next time when I need to upgrade the version I will check this too. Thank you for your comment.